# Sending an array that's not in a form through mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, forms, mongoose

I'm making an intranet application with node.js and use body-parser and mongoose to send form data to my database. The specific form makes a post on the website which works as it should. However, I want to add the feature to add tags to the post, which the user choose by clicking an  tag and that tags innerHTML is added to an array through Javascript. What I'm wondering is how to send that array through mongoose to save it in the databse even though the array is not in the form data. How could I solve this is the best possible way?

The array I want to send through is the "tagsList" one.

Please inform me if there's something I should be more clear about.

Html:

```
<div class="ui red attached secondary segment clearfix">
  <div class="item">
    <form class ="ui form" action="/" method="POST">
        <div class="field">
            <textarea rows="1" name="post[body]" placeholder="Write a post" 
    required></textarea>

        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="column" id="tagsField">
                <div class="box wrap">
                    <div class="inside"><a class="ui red tiny label" 
                    onclick="changeTag(this)">Daily Shopping</a></div>
                    <div class="inside"><a class="ui blue tiny label" 
                    onclick="changeTag(this)">Managers</a></div>
                    <div class="inside"><a class="ui orange tiny label" 
                    onclick="changeTag(this)">Lund</a></div>
                    <div class="inside"><a class="ui black tiny label" 
                    onclick="changeTag(this)">Malmör</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column" id="buttonField">
            <button type="submit" class="ui positive button">Post</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var tagsList = [];

function changeTag(i) {
    $(i).toggleClass("tag");
    var index = tagsList.indexOf(i.innerHTML);
    if(index == -1){
        tagsList.push(i.innerHTML);
    }
    else{
        tagsList.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Node:

```
//SCHEMA CONFIG
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: String, 
    tags: [
        {
            type: String
        }
    ],
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);

//ROUTES
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    Post.find({}, function(err, allPosts){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else {
            res.render("index", {posts: allPosts});
        }
    });
});
app.post("/", function(req, res){
    req.body.post.body = req.sanitize(req.body.post.body);
    Post.create(req.body.post, function(err, newPost){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       }else{
           res.redirect("/");
       }
   }) 
});
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. They are as different as Austria and Australia. What you have here is JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a Post.create() method? If so post it so that I can  get a clear understanding of what you are doing

seems for now is you are having trouble how to send data to back end post req you have on node .. 
So you can use Jquery and make an asnyc request to the server using AJAX
you can use Jquery's built in method called

```
var data ={
   // here you make your post request using a proper json annotation so that  
   // you can send the whole object to the backend without any fuss
};

$.ajax(()=>{
   method:"post",
   url:"your url end point",
   data: data, // this is you object of data you want to send to the server
   success:(data)=>{
      console.log("post success...");
   },
   error:()=>{
     console.log("500 error");
   }
});
```